# Quarto Book Download button

Tags: r, quarto

Using `bookdown` we are able to download different file formats from a download button, e.g.

```
---
bookdown::gitbook:
   download:
      - ["test.pdf", "PDF File"]
      - ["test.html", "HTML File"]
      - ["test.csv", "Data test.csv"]
---
```

In quarto, we only have the [options](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/projects/books.html) for downloads: (one or more of pdf, epub, and docx). Has somebody an idea how to include data (e.g. `.csv` or `.qs`) via a download button to include on navbar or preferably sidebar?

**Edit 1**: After the great answer of @shafee, here is how my book at the moment looks like and where I would like to add the option to download the data.

[image: example_sidebar]

By clicking on the downarrow, a dropdown menu opens and there I would like to add the option (optimal would be more than one, i.e. many datasets) "Download Data". Here is an example `.yml`:

```
---
project:
  type: book
  
book:
  title: "Quarto Book"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd
       
  sidebar:
    pinned: true
    
  repo-url: https://www.rstudio.com/   
  search: 
    location: sidebar
    type: textbox
  downloads: [pdf, epub]
    
format:
  html:
   # include-after-body: custom.html
    theme: cosmo
---
```

**Edit 2**: There could be a way using the `tools` option in the `sidebar`. Maybe someone has an idea how to correctly generate an URL for the data such that it will be downloaded directly.

```
  sidebar:
    pinned: true
    tools:
      - icon: save
        menu:
          - text: Data XLSX
            url:  ymlthis::yml_params_code(browseURL('data/mtcars.xlsx'))
          - text: Data CSV
            url:  ymlthis::yml_params_code(browseURL('data/mtcars.csv'))
```

[image: ex_2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Updated Answer (Corresponding To OP's 2nd Edit)

The concept remains the same. Here we are just replacing those menu items under the tools with the button created from *index.qmd* file using javascript.

**If you need to add more `csv` or `xlsx` data, just add the corresponding code for creating button inside the `.download_btn` pandoc divs and add more `- text: ""` and `url: "#"` in the `_quarto.yml` file.**

---

**_quarto.yml**

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: "Quarto Book"
  author: "Jane Doe"
  date: "9/29/2022"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd

  downloads: [pdf, epub]
  sidebar:
    pinned: true
    tools:
      - icon: save
        menu:
          - text: ""
            url:  "#"
          - text: ""
            url:  "#"
          - text: ""
            url:  "#"
            
  repo-url: https://www.rstudio.com/   
  search: 
    location: sidebar
    type: textbox

format:
  html:
    include-after-body: custom.html
    theme: cosmo
```

---

**index.qmd**

````
# Preface {.unnumbered}

This is a Quarto book.


::: {.download_btn}

```{css}
#| echo: false

.btn-default,
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:active {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  color: grey;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

```


```{r}
#| echo: false

library(downloadthis)

mtcars %>%
  download_this(
    output_name = "mtcars data set",
    output_extension = ".csv",
    button_label = "mtcars.csv",
    button_type = "default",
    has_icon = TRUE,
    icon = "fa fa-file-csv"
  )
```


```{r}
#| echo: false

iris %>%
  download_this(
    output_name = "Iris data set",
    output_extension = ".csv",
    button_label = "iris.csv",
    button_type = "default",
    has_icon = TRUE,
    icon = "fa fa-file-csv"
  )
```

```{r}
#| echo: false

palmerpenguins::penguins %>%
  download_this(
    output_name = "penguins data set",
    output_extension = ".csv",
    button_label = "penguins.csv",
    button_type = "default",
    has_icon = TRUE,
    icon = "fa fa-file-csv"
  )
```

:::
````

---

**custom.html**

```
<script>
var all_btns = document.querySelectorAll(".download_btn a");
var data_nav = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-labelledby="sidebar-tool-dropdown-0"] li')

for (let i = 0; i < data_nav.length; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(all_btns[i]);
  data_nav[i].parentElement.replaceChild(li, data_nav[i])
}

</script>
```

---

[image: csv download option when the save button is click]

---

## Old Answer

Since so far there's no default option from Quarto to add buttons for downloading `csv` data, as a workaround we can add a download button in the Book navbar with the help of [`{downloadthis}`](https://fmmattioni.github.io/downloadthis/) R-package and using a few line of javascript code.

So at first, add the code for creating button and a bit `css` to style the button's appearance in the *index.qmd* file with `echo: false`.

**index.qmd**

---

````
# Preface {.unnumbered}

This is a Quarto book.

::: {.download_btn}

```{css}
#| echo: false

.btn-default,
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:active {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  color: whitesmoke;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

```


```{r}
#| echo: false

library(downloadthis)

mtcars %>%
  download_this(
    output_name = "mtcars data set",
    output_extension = ".csv",
    button_label = "",
    button_type = "default",
    has_icon = TRUE,
    icon = "fa fa-file-csv"
  )
```

:::
````

---

Now by default, the button will be created in the book body of the index page. But we want this in the book navbar. To do that, we can add a `save icon` with `href: "#"` as a placeholder in the right side of the navbar, and then using javascript we can replace this save icon with our created download button.

Now to add js code, create an html file *custom.html* and put these lines of codes in that file and then add this *custom.html* file with `include-after-body: custom.html` in `_quarto.yml`.

**custom.html**

---

```
<script>

var btn = document.querySelector(".download_btn");
var nav = document.querySelector(".navbar-nav .bi-save");
nav.parentElement.replaceChild(btn, nav);

</script>
```

**_quarto.yml**

---

```
project:
  type: book
  
book:
  title: "Quarto Book"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd
  navbar:
   right: 
     - icon: save
       href: "#"
    
format:
  html:
    include-after-body: custom.html
    theme: cosmo
```

Now the rendered book navbar looks like,

---

[image: csv file download button in navbar]

---

Refer to the [`downloadthis package documentation`](https://fmmattioni.github.io/downloadthis/articles/downloadthis.html) to know about various options for adding buttons to download `csv` or `xlsx` files or any R-object as `rds` file and to know about how to style the buttons.

***Disclaimer: I am just an R-user and know just a little bit javascript. So anyone, please feel free to edit this answer with more efficient js code.*** :-)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, your answer works, but I was wondering if we can control the download placement such that it also works with the dropdown menu - see my edit.

Comment: That would be more complicated to do I think. And Its already enough complicated : ).

Comment: Maybe your solution is a starting point for others who may have an idea how that could be possible. My issue in the end is that I have several datasets that I would like to be downloadable for the user.  Great answer nevertheless and thank you for answering so many Quarto and RMarkdown questions:)

Comment: Well, for you case, one possible solution could be,  you can host multiple dataset as zipped file in your github repo and then use the [`download_link`](https://fmmattioni.github.io/downloadthis/reference/download_link.html) button. Would that work for you?

Comment: Yes and no :D I would rather prefer a dropdown such that the user can decide on the specific file one wants to download and not all of them. But it could be a compromise, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: See the updated answer. :D

Answer (score 1):

A solution without an external package works very similar to my 2nd edit (assuming that the data is stored in folder `data`:

```
  sidebar:
    pinned: true
    tools:
          - icon: save
            menu:
              - text: Data XLSX
                url:  "data/mtcars.xlsx"
              - text: Data CSV
                url:  "data/mtcars.csv"
```

Comment: simple and straightforward solution!